# Why isn't parallel programming used more often?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I've been doing software development (in Java) since 1998 and have worked with many different teams solving various different problems. Never during time period has any team used parallel programming methods. Even though multi-core processors have been around for a while, I find that parallel programming models are still largely ignored in the real world to solve problems. So, why is parallel programming not used more often? It seems like a good way to make things more scalable, efficient and generally improve performance of programs.

Comment: Wrong place to ask. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is more relevant. Short answer, parallel programming is really hard.

Comment: Just curious: What kind of problems have you been working on?

Comment: Fun side note, parallel programming is used a lot in biophysics and females are predominantly adapted to the way of thinking required for it.

Answer (score 1):

Because getting parallel programming right in a multithreaded shared-memory environment like Java is really, *really* hard. You're practically guaranteed to make mistakes that are very hard to diagnose. And of course it's extra effort.

Furthermore, the kind of programs that most people work on are workflow systems. Desktop versions of those aren't performance-critical, and webapps / server components are trivial to parallelize by having each request be served by its own thread. This has the advantage that developers don't really have to deal with the parallel aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Because parallel programming is not applicable to every possible problem and because writing a correct concurrent program is hard. Especially making sure that threads are synchronized correctly without unnecessary locking is just not easy. Also, bugs that happen depending on the timing of thread scheduling are very hard to reproduce, find and fix. It's very nasty if you have a concurrency bug that happens once every 100,000 transactions and it happens on production and not on your development system (I've been there...).

Read the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/), the best book about concurrent programming in Java.

Answer (score 1):

> parallel programming models are still largely ignored in the real world to solve problems

I think it *is* being used where it solves problems. But it doesn't come for free, so it's indeed better not to do anything in parallel (asynchronously) when a simpler serial (synchronous) solution works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Real parallel programming (where you split up a problem over several cores) is mostly interesting for long running algorithms. Most real life applications are more event processors. Often these events will run in parallel (think about a web server having several threads to process requests). when programming is used to solve an arithmetic problem, it is used more often (think optimization, data analysis etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think your opinion is wrong, for sample when you are have a server side application, application server handle any request by a thread(maybe achieve it from thread-pool).

I guess any place that need to parallel(multi-threading) model you have to do programming parallel.

There is usefull information in following link :

- http://www.asjava.com/core-java/why-we-need-to-use-multiple-threads/